# Jenkins Error cloning remote repo 'origin'

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-agent

I have more than 5 jenkins nodes and all working perfectly. My repository on bitbucket. I recently create a new node and it gives me this error.

```
Started by user David

Building remotely on Harry's Node (harryNode) in workspace D:\workspace\Build Of Material
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository https://david119@bitbucket.org/david119/Systembreakdown.git
 > git init D:\workspace\Build Of Material # timeout=10
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not init D:\workspace\Build Of Material
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$5.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:747)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$2.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:539)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$1.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:153)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$1.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:146)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:153)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:50)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:336)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine$1$1.run(Engine.java:94)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at ......remote call to JNLP4-connect connection from 192.168.80.152/192.168.80.152:31219(Native Method)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1545)
    at hudson.remoting.UserResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:253)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:830)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler.execute(RemoteGitImpl.java:146)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor497.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteGitImpl.java:132)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy74.execute(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1083)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1123)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:495)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1276)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:560)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:485)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1735)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:543)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:405)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Error performing command: git init D:\workspace\Build Of Material
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1977)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1938)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1934)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommand(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1572)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$5.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:745)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$2.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:539)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$1.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:153)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$1.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:146)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:153)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:50)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:336)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine$1$1.run(Engine.java:94)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "git" (in directory "D:\workspace\Build Of Material"): CreateProcess error=87, The parameter is incorrect
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:245)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:214)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:850)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:384)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1966)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=87, The parameter is incorrect
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 22 more
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
TestNG Reports Processing: START
Looking for TestNG results report in workspace using pattern: **/testng-results.xml
Did not find any matching files.
Finished: FAILURE
```

This is my Git global tool settings on Jenkins. this settings work perfectly with all other.

[image]

Environment variable also set correctly on system variables.

Hope these information will enough to solve the problem.

Comment: Are others also contain space in their path?

Comment: Which path ? can you explain it little bit

Comment: `D:\workspace\Build Of Material`

Comment: yah that's totally fine with other nodes

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the Jenkins Git Plugin executes ** before ** the environment is inherited.

SET YOUR SLAVE's PATH to Git ( Just DO IT !! )

1) Go to your Windows slave configuration Manage Jenkins > Manage Nodes

2) Select your slave configuration

3) Check Tool Locations under Node Properties

4) Enter complete path to git executable including git.exe

[x] Tool Locations
   Name: (GIT) git
   Home: C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe

Comment: No it won't work after initializing the git home path

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to Global Tools Configuration under manage and change the default git configuration or add a new git configuration.